# libusb_open returns LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED on windows 10

Tags: c++, libusb, cd

OS: Windows 10 64bit

Compiler: MSVC 19 std:c++20

static linking

I have below code which just initialize and print some information about the device

```
#include "libusb.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  libusb_context* cntx{ nullptr };
  int status{ libusb_init(&cntx) };
  if (status != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
  {
    std::cerr << libusb_strerror(status);
    return -1;
  }
  libusb_device** devices;
  ssize_t numberOfDevices{ libusb_get_device_list(cntx, &devices) };
  if (numberOfDevices <= 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "Device does NOT found\n";
    return -1;
  }
  std::cout << "Found " << numberOfDevices << " Devices\n";
  int index{ 0 };
  std::cout << std::hex;
  std::cout << "Device Address: " << +libusb_get_device_address(devices[index]) << '\n'
            << "Port Number: "    << +libusb_get_port_number(devices[index]) << '\n'
            << "Bus Number: "     << +libusb_get_bus_number(devices[index]) << '\n'
            << "Device Speed: ";
  switch (libusb_get_device_speed(devices[index])
  {
  case LIBUSB_SPEED_SUPER:      std::cout << "5Gb\n";     break;
  case LIBUSB_SPEED_SUPER_PLUS: std::cout << "10Gb\n";    break;
  case LIBUSB_SPEED_FULL:       std::cout << "12Mb\n";    break;
  case LIBUSB_SPEED_LOW:        std::cout << "1.5Mb\n";   break;
  case LIBUSB_SPEED_HIGH:       std::cout << "480Mb\n";   break;
  default:                      std::cout << "UNKNOWN\n"; break;
  }
```

so far so good, but when I want to open the (for example) devices[0], `LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED` will return:

```
  constexpr std::uint16_t VID{ 0x8086 };
  constexpr std::uint16_t PID{ 0x1D26 };
  libusb_device_handle* device{ nullptr };
  status = libusb_open(devices[index], &device);
  if (status)
  {
    std::cerr << "Can NOT open the device: " << libusb_strerror(status) << '\n';
    device = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(cntx, VID, PID);
    if (!device)
    { 
      std::cerr << "Can NOT open the device with VID & PID\n";
      return -1;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Device opened\n";
  return 0;
}
```

neither works.
btw, the device was programmed by a micro-programmer so I don't know about how he programmed it, my job is just to get data from the device.

Comment: Using *libusb*, you can only open USB devices that are using the WinUSB (or libusbK and libusb0) drivers. To verify if this is the case, use [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) to install WinUSB for your device. If this is appropriate for the device, it can be slightly reprogrammed such that Windows installs WinUSB automatically.

Comment: Warning: 0x8086 / 0x1D26 seems to be for a Intel USB host controller. If so, do not change the driver. Your PC won't boot anymore. Only do it for device you can unplug.

Comment: @Codo Thanks a lot for warning, I replace driver with Zadig, but what about the customer, does that extract file is enough for the customer?, first time working with Zadig.

Comment: What's the state now? Did you make any progress by installing the WinUSB driver for your device? Is this appropriate for you device, i.e. it does not disable anything else?

Comment: @Codo I can open the device for now, next step is to get data from it. Thanks a lot. If you desire, please make that comment an answer to check that and close the question. <3

Comment: Great to hear. The driver installation can be automated by implementing [WCID](https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/WCID-Devices) or [Microsoft OS 2.0 descriptor](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/6/3563ED4A-F318-4B66-A181-AB1D8F6FD42D/MS_OS_2_0_desc.docx) on the device.

Comment: I have the same issue with a plain J-Link EDU Mini debugger. It was working earlier on Windows 10. I guess after a J-Link driver update, Windows update or reinstalling Windows it stopped working.
The OpenOCD package is the same, but does not work with the latest (0.12) either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*libusb* can enumerate all USB devices. But it can only open devices that have the *WinUSB* driver (or *libusbK* or *libusb0*) installed. *WinUSB* is the generic driver to interact directly with USB devices and their endpoints, without the need for implementing and providing your own device driver.

This is appropriate if the device does not implement any of the standard USB protocols (mass storage, camera, audio, serial port etc.), for which Windows provides and loads standard drivers, and if the device does not come with its own driver that needs to be installed first.

On Linux and macOS, this is a non-issue as USB devices without a dedicated driver are available to applications without any driver hassles.

In order to install *WinUSB*, [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) can be used. Make sure you select the correct device, which can be unplugged if a problem occurs. If the driver is replaced for a crucial device such a USB host controller, a keyboard etc., the PC might no longer boot.

To automate the *WinUSB* installation, the device can implement additional USB control requests. There are two options:

- [WCID](https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/WCID-Devices)
- [Microsoft OS 2.0 descriptor](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/6/3563ED4A-F318-4B66-A181-AB1D8F6FD42D/MS_OS_2_0_desc.docx)

Comment: Does such a layer exist that can make Win32 SetupAPI based driver "act/spoof/fake/mock" libusb? Would it theoretically be possible for simple actions like list devices, open device, find interfaces/endpoints, bulk transfer in (read) + bulk transfer out (write)?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Interact with USB devices without installing WinUSB driver? If so, the answer is no. These devices are not accessible because they either have no driver at all, or because they use another driver that has exclusive address to the device.

Comment: I have a device that has its own driver that I didn't write that as far as I can tell does nothing differently than a WinUSB driver would in terms of what it enables the operating system to do with the device. Meaning, it gets the device handle (like libusb), finds the configuration/interfaces/endpoints, then does bulk transfer in/out on them. The only difference is applications using it do not expect the WinUSB driver, it expects the GUID for its own driver that does serial under the hood. I want to do USB-IP to this device, but Windows applications using it don't expect WinUSB.

Comment: You better start a separate question and describe exactly what the driver does and and what you want do achieve. It's a bit confusing to me.

Comment: I think you touched on the point that it's "not possible". What's funny is in the libusb codebase (the Windows implementation), it uses SetupAPI to do exactly what I'm talking about, but I think it requests the device with the WinUSB driver GUID instead of your own custom. I think that's the only difference unless I'm missing something. Is it possible for device drivers to do custom things under the hood that *don't* boil down to "transfer in/out to endpoints" with USB devices?

Comment: No, that's not possible. This is given, both by the USB protocol itself and by the many drivers between the USB device and the Windows USB device drivers, most notably the Windows USB host controller driver.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the Libusb-WinUSB driver fixed my problem. zadig didn't find my ESP-PROG board but https://visualgdb.com/UsbDriverTool/ did.
Connect ESP-PROG if you will be using it.
Download and run https://visualgdb.com/UsbDriverTool/
Look for the device matching vendor ID 0403 and product ID 6010.
Change the driver to Libusb-WinUSB.

Comment: zadig does found my board and install the Libusb-WinUSB driver and fix it but another problem was occurred which doesn't relate to this question... anyway, thanks.